# Remove HTML li and text from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding HTML from my JavaScript a remove button with text. I want to remove the li and the text with it.

I believe that I am not correctly finding the li item to remove it.

Any help is appreciated!

```
$("#add_btn").click(function() {

    var job = $("#add_task").val().trim();

    if (job.length != 0) {
        $("#theList").append(
            '<li>' + '<button id="remove_btn">Remove</button>' + job + '</li>'
            );
    } else {
        window.alert("Don't add blank job");
    }
});

$("#remove_btn").click(function() { 
    //intended to remove li and text... 
    $(this).next().remove(); //this is not working
});
```

Below is the HTML:

```
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>To Do List</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="toDoList.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>To Do List</h1>

    <label for="add_task">Add Task:</label>
    <input type="text" id="add_task" name="add_task">
    <br>

    <button id="add_btn">
        Add the task
    </button>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <h2>My To Do List</h2>
    <ol id="theList">
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your html as well.

Comment: @jrummell and the two others, Not required.

Comment: The `<button>` element has no `next()` element, there's nothing following it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar It's difficult to see what element `$(this).next()` is referencing without the `HTML`, which is the cause of his problem.

Comment: @NickZ There's no `next()` element. Looks like OP doesn't know to use it.

Comment: Well, there could be, if the value from the `#add_task` element is HTML ?

Comment: @adeneo I doubt that. Looks like no one would put a HTML value in that! `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `id` in a repetitive place. I am updating your code with a few corrections:

```js
$("#add_btn").click(function() {
  var job = $("#add_task").val().trim();
  if (job.length != 0) {
    $("#theList").append(
      //----------------v---v: Change ID to Class. You are repeating.           «««««
      '<li>' + '<button class="remove_btn">Remove</button>' + job + '</li>'
    );
  } else {
    window.alert("Don't add blank job");
  }
});

// Delegate the event.                                                          «««««
$("#theList").on("click", ".remove_btn", function() { 
  //intended to remove li and text... 
  // Change to closest as the button is inside the `<li>`                       «««««
  $(this).closest("li").remove(); // this will work
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("#add_btn").click(function() {
    var job = $("#add_task").val().trim();
    if (job.length != 0) {
      $("#theList").append(
        //----------------v---v: Change ID to Class. You are repeating.
        '<li>' + '<button class="remove_btn">Remove</button>' + job + '</li>'
      );
    } else {
      window.alert("Don't add blank job");
    }
  });

  // Delegate the event.
  $("#theList").on("click", ".remove_btn", function() { 
    //intended to remove li and text... 
    // Change to closest as the button is inside the `<li>`
    $(this).closest("li").remove(); // this will work
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>To Do List</h1>

<label for="add_task">Add Task:</label>
<input type="text" id="add_task" name="add_task">
<br>

<button id="add_btn">
  Add the task
</button>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<h2>My To Do List</h2>
<ol id="theList">
</ol>
```

Comment: That use of comment: `//----------------v---v: ` is clever.

Comment: Thanks @zer00ne! `:D`